# Script vb para chamar um executável

Tags: vbs

Por favor alguém pode me ajudar, tenho este código abaixo, salvei em **vbs**, o problema ocorre nas duas linhas que tem **exeName**, se o código estiver salvo com a primeira linha, ele funciona, se estiver salvo com a segunda linha ele não encontra o arquivo, no entanto, o arquivo existe, se eu copiar e colar no Executar do Windows ele abre o programa. O erro que aparece é: O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.

```
strComputer = "."
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Dim exeName 
Dim statusCode 
exeName = "%windir%\notepad"
exeName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Lancamentos.net\Lancamentos.exe"
statusCode = WshShell.Run (exeName, 1, true) 
MsgBox("Fim do programa")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema ocorre porque o *path* que você está tentando executar possui espaços:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Lancamentos.net\Lancamentos.exe
```

Nesse caso, você deve acrescentar duas aspas extras para que o *path* seja interpretado de maneira correta:

```
exeName = """Program Files (x86)\Lancamentos.net\Lancamentos.exe"""
```

Comment: Thomas, resolveu amigo, muito obrigado.

Comment: Ótimo @userTi. Pode, por gentileza, marcar a resposta como solução? Abraço

Comment: Marcada, mais uma vez, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```bat
exeName = "%windir%\notepad"
```

- Para expandir a variável `%windir%` no código, você pode usar:

```bat
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")
wshShell = Nothing
```


        <sup>***lincado com Rob van der Woude's Sript Pages - Environment Variables***</sup>

- Você não precisa definir uma variável para chamar o seu programa `Lancamentos.exe` quando não vais utilizar um controle para possível erro/aviso, ou  até mesmo pegar as strings de saída:

```bat
strWinDir = (CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%"))
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run strWinDir&"\notepad.exe",1,false

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Lancamentos.net\Lancamentos.exe""",1,true
MsgBox("Fim do programa")
```